# Yandex Карты API 2.0 : как можно получить balloonContent из click event на Placemark

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Тут добавляю Placemark:

```
 var placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([lat,long],
                        { 
                            hintContent:HintContent
                        },
                        { 
                           draggable: false,
                           hintOptions: { showTimeout: 500
                        }         
                );
```

Здесь добавляю event:

```
 placemark.events.add('click', function(e) {
       //здесь получаю координаты
      var coords = e.get('coordPosition');
    //как можно из e получить balloonContent?
     
     });
```

Comment: нашел,так можно получить=> var geoObject = e.get('target'); geoObject.properties._T.balloonContent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как получить текущий контент я не нашел. Зато вот таким образом можно обратиться и получить любые свойства вашего `PlaceMark`:

```
e.get('target')['properties'].get('balloonContent')
```

Также при создании `placemark` вы можете прописать кастомные атрибуты. И через event таким образом их получить.